# Cloudfront CDN to honor client Cache-Control: no-store (no-cache) request headers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

When a request is made from the client, to a Cloudfront CDN endpoint with **request header**

```
Cache-Control: no-store
```

Cloudfront still returns data from its cache, and does not query the origin server.

(Looking for behavior like in the user browser, ie when request header no-store is provided it skips the cache and hits the URL)

For Example : Making this request via Postman. I add cache-contol: no-store, and expect it to bypass the cache

[image]

This is possible in Google CDN (honors: no-store), is there some way to achieve this in Cloudfront CDN ?

Note : I am talking of headers being sent from the client to the CDN Endpoint, (**Request Headers**) and not headers sent from the origin (**Response Headers**).

Comment: The question isn't clear enough but CloudFront honors no-store as well unless you have configured min ttl to some high value and asking CloudFront to cache it specifically, Same goes for Google Cloud CDN when you choose FORCE_CACHE_ALL

Comment: @JamesDean Unable to find any doc on this. But have set minTTL to be 0.

Comment: Just to make it more clear, I am talking of headers being sent from the client to the cdn, (Request Headers) and not headers sent from the origin (Response Headers). In the latter what you said applies.

Comment: @Sunny any news about it?, I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope was not able to find a proper way to do this. What can be done is if the client sends a no-cache, the server code should read this header and send back a no-cache to prevent cloudfront from caching it.  It will require code change for endpoints. - @angel.teran

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Sunnny. In any case, I'm going to create a support case to ask about it but I'm afraid CloudFront doesn't support the Cache-Control header in the request.